# Prove that $x=5\cos(6x)$ for some $x$ in the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

> Prove that $x=5\cos(6x)$ for some $x$ in the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ using the the IVT

I'm not entirely sure how to prove this but I set it up this way:

> $f(x)=x-5\cos(6x)$

And so

> $f(a)=f\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}+5$

And

> $f(b)=f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}-5$

And so by the intermediate value theorem:

> $f\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\lt 0\lt f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think you're good to go, might be worth explicitly stating that $f$ is continuous in your interval.

Comment: @ZainPatel OK, so I can say, "Since $f$ is continuous from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$ then blah blah blah?"

Comment: "Since $f$ is continuous in $\left(\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3}\right)$, then blah blah..."

Comment: @ZainPatel thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct except for two details.

(1) you need to add explicitly that $f$ is continuous. In other words, "since $f$ is continuous on $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}]$ it follows from the IVT that $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3})$. [Thanks to @ZainPatel ]

(2) you garbled your signs near the end it is $$f\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)>0>f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$

[image]